# Elasticsearch aggregate on multi-field or group by multifield

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch, group-by

I have data in the below format

```
src_ip     dst_ip     size
1.1.1.1    2.2.2.2    80
```

I'm trying to use elastic to reach the same result as SQL statememt

```
select src_ip, dst_ip, sum(size) from table order by sum(size) limit 1:10
```

In other words I`m trying to get the top 10 result after aggregated by src_ip and dst_ip.

I know I can do bucket aggregate like below:

```
"aggs":
{
    "SRC_IP": 
    { 
        "terms": { "field": "SRC_IP"},
        "aggs": 
        {
            "DST_IP":
            {
                "terms": { "field": "DST_IP"} ,  
                "aggs": 
                {
                            "totalPACKETS": { "sum": { "field": "PACKETS" } }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is, in this way, the result is not ordered by sum(size). Even I add a order sub-clause, it can only order by sum(size) in one bucket, not sorted in the global scope.

Can any one tell how to do it please?

Comment: Refer this https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/1.x/_sorting_based_on_deep_metrics.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be accomplished using script feature. For example :

```
  "aggs":
    {
      "SRC_DST":
        {
          "terms": {"script": "[doc.SRC_IP.value, doc.DST_IP.value].join(\"-\")","size": 2,"shard_size":0, "order": {"sum_bits": "desc"}},
          "aggs": { "sum_bits": { "sum": {"field": "BYTES"} } }
        }
    }
```